# Stop Shiny app from outside the App

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have a locally deployed shiny Application.

I want to run a scheduled R script to stop the App (if it is already running), update some data and the run the app again.

My issue is that I don't know how to stop the App from outside the App (knowing the host address and the source file directory).
I want an equivalent for this:

`shiny::runApp(appDir = 'C:/***', host = "10.***", port = 5050, launch.browser = TRUE)`

but this time for stopping the App and not running it.

Appreciate your help !

[r](/questions/tagged/r)[rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio)[shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny)[taskscheduler](/questions/tagged/taskscheduler)

Comment: Anyone could help please ?

Comment: anyone who can help with this ?